# How to publish to stream multiple images with Facebook Graph api?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'd like to attach not just one picture, but multiple, as in 2 or more to the wall. How can I achieve this with the Graph API? I recall some other app companies were doing this and I want to know how they achieved this.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to allow users to upload photos to your own server and then allow the user to submit the photos to facebook.

> $file = 'path_to_image'; // Dont forget to add $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
>   $photo_details['image'] = '@' . realpath($file);
>
> $upload_photo = $facebook-api('/me/photos','post',$photo_details);

The photos will be uploaded to your application's album. Alternatively you can substitute "/me/photos" for "/$album_id/photos", if you wish to upload your photos to a specific album.

When you upload several photos ( even if there is some delay between uploads ) the story in the news feed will contain previews of three of the recently uploaded photos.